# How to fetch data that is in JSON format from an API using python to a .db file

Tags: python, mysql, json, sqlite, python-requests

I have an API: https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/gf?game_pk=635886
I want to fetch the data from here (which is in JSON format) using a python code and create a table filled with this data so that I can run SQL queries on it using sqlite3. I have gotten the data here in JSON, but I want to push it to my database called pitch.db

Here is what I have so far:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    import sqlite3
    import json
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=False)
    url = "https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/gf?game_pk=635886"
    conn = sqlite3.connect('pitch.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    df = pd.read_json(url, orient='index')
    df.to_sql('baseball', engine, if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: there might be something better, but to get you moving you could use the `pandas` library, which creates and works with dataframes (basically tables). you could use `pandas.read_json` to bring in your data into a structure you can work with and then `pandas.to_sql` can use sqlite3 to push things to a database (even if it is just in memory). you can use pandas to analyze the data as well.

Comment: So I tried that and I am getting an error:
Here is the Code:
```import sqlite3
import requests
import pandas as pd
url = "https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/gf?game_pk=635886"
req = requests.get(url)
r = req.json()
import pprint
df = pd.DataFrame(r)
pprint(df)```

ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length

Comment: what data are you trying to insert? The json is a deeply nested structure. You'll need to flatten it out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here's an example of getting the pitchers into the db. You have to flatten out the json, and then also either a) flatten out any reaming json structures in the columns, or drop them (I dropped them as I don't know what data you want exactly). But this puts the table in db file called pitchers, with table baseball.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import sqlite3

url = url = "https://baseballsavant.mlb.com/gf?game_pk=635886"
jsonData = requests.get(url).json()

pitchers = []
for home_away in ['home', 'away']:
    for x in jsonData[f'{home_away}_pitchers'].values():
        pitchers += x
    
pitchers_df = pd.DataFrame(pitchers)
cols = ['play_id','inning','ab_number','outs','stand','batter_name','p_throws',
        'pitcher_name','team_batting','team_fielding','result','strikes',
        'balls','pre_strikes','pre_balls','call_name','pitch_type','start_speed',
        'extension','zone','spin_rate','hit_speed','hit_distance','hit_angle',
        'is_barrel','is_bip_out','pitch_number','player_total_pitches',
        'game_pk']
pitchers_df = pitchers_df[cols]

conn = sqlite3.connect('pitch.db')
pitchers_df.to_sql('baseball', conn, if_exists='replace',  index=False)
conn.close()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I want values like: * play_id
* inning
* ab_number
* outs
* stand
* batter_name
* p_throws
* pitcher_name
* team_batting
* team_fielding
* result
in my db. Any idea how to flatten to get these pushed into my db?

Comment: Ok. I’ll add that tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, updated the code.

Comment: This works, thanks it helped me understand SQL better!